# How to view the history of edits on a question or answer

Tags: support, feature-request

It's fairly common to see someone referring to an edit or deleted comment, but without the original item they're referring to, there's no context.

Is there a way to view the edit history of a question and/or answer? Or see a deleted comment? I would assume either feature would require a certain amount of rep, so if these features exist, how much is needed?

Also, if this feature doesn't exist, is it something we can add, like a History tab?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The text "edited x minutes/hours/days ago" under the post is a link to the post's history, including locks, close and reopen, delete and undelete, and which everyone can see*. Moderators can see deleted comments, but no one else can.

*: edits by the same user within 5 minutes fall into a "grace period" and no record of those edits is kept.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that worked for other people's posts as well. Thanks Kevin - accepted!

Answer (score 3):

There's another option as well: the timeline.

If you take the URL of a post, for instance

> [`https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5313/how-to-view-the-history-of-edits-on-a-question-or-answer`](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5313/how-to-view-the-history-of-edits-on-a-question-or-answer)

and change "questions" to "posts" and replace everything after the post id with "timeline", you get to see the timeline of a post:

> [`https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/5313/timeline`](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/5313/timeline)

Comment: Nope, they did remember to hide deleted comments from it.  Darn  =P